# What does figure mean in "figure of speech"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I know the phase "figure of speech" means *a word or phrase used in a nonliteral sense to add rhetorical force to a spoken or written passage*. But I don't get the phase when I break it into single words.

What does "figure" mean here?

Comment: Did you do any research on what figure *might* mean?

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, I have explored its every meaning in New Oxford American Dictionary, but without a good matching from my point of view. I also searched in the old posts in ELL.SE, no relevant post is found.

Comment: Oh, yeah. The definitions in the online oxford dictionary for figure are pretty bad. They always try to get so specific.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a 'figure' is a shape or pattern. It is the form of something. For some reason, the online [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/figure) have indicated the closest general meaning as archaic:

> 3.4 *archaic* The external form or shape of a thing.

I usually start with Wiktionary, myself. Wiktionary's [entry for 'figure'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/figure) has some applicable definitions:

> 2. The representation of any form, as by drawing, painting, modelling, carving, embroidering, etc.; especially, a representation of the human body
> 3. A shape.
> 4. A visible pattern as in wood or cloth.

So it doesn't have to be a person, like the Oxford entries might lead you to believe. Ignore the bit about wood and cloth in 4. Any visible pattern is a figure.

So, if we have a set pattern of words that we say the same way each time, in other words a *pattern* of speech, that's a figure of speech.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for an answer to the same question. Here is my little research

We have a literal meaning and a non-literal meaning

The non-literal meaning is figurative. The words become ***a symbol*** for something else beyond the literal meaning, the non-literal one.

Figurative has the *sense of* using words to ***paint/draw/sketch/build/*** [non-literal meanings].

You could check the two entries below for help.

---

**The Online Etymology Dictionary**

> figure (n.) c. 1200, "numeral;" mid-13c., "visible appearance of a
>   person;" late 14c., "visible and tangible form of anything," from Old
>   French **figure "shape, body; form of a word; figure of speech;
>   symbol, allegory" (10c)**, from Latin figura "a shape, form, figure;
>   quality, kind, style; figure of speech," in Late Latin "**a sketch,
>   drawing,**" from PIE *dheigh- "**to form, build**" (see dough).

---

**Collins COBUILD Advanced Learner's English Dictionary**

> **Allegory:**
>
> An allegory is a story, poem, or **painting** in which the characters
>   and events are **symbols of something else**. Allegories are often
>   moral, religious, or political.
>
> *The book is a kind of allegory of Latin American history.*